# Need aid on Python 3.4.1 with winsound

Tags: python, audio, tkinter

I'm fairly new to Python. I decided to try and write a simple program that allowed me to play an audio file. After hours of research, I found out about `winsound` and various different ways to use it. However,  have come to some confusion.

On one of the many help guides, I was told to put the audio files in a folder somewhere on the computer. Pretty unhelpful.

I created a folder in the `C:\\ drive` named Vsim, for Voice Simulator. Placing the audio in an audio file within Vsim, I attempted to link the two together. That's where everything blew up in my face...

```
from tkinter import *
import sys, random, winsound, tkinter.messagebox, time

if "C:\\Vsim" not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append("C:\\Vsim")

def Audio():
     winsound.PlaySound("audio/ugh.wav", winsound.SND_NODEFAULT)

mgui = Tk()
r = random
m = tkinter.messagebox


mgui.title("Voice Simulator")
mgui.geometry("500x250")
mgui.resizable(height = 0, width = 0)
mgui.configure(bg = "black")

label1 = Label(mgui, text = "Voice Simulator Alpha", fg = "green", bg   = "black")
label1.pack(side = TOP)
label2 = Label(mgui, text = "Please Enter Your Text:", fg = "red", bg = "black")
label2.pack(side = TOP)

txtbox = StringVar()
entry1 = Entry(mgui, textvariable = txtbox)
entry1.pack(side = TOP)

button1 = Button(mgui, text = "Create Audio!", fg = "blue", bg = "yellow", command =  Audio)
button1.pack(side = TOP)


mgui.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is?

Comment: Basically, I am having a large amount of difficulty with playing a .wav sound through tkinter. What I want to happen at this point in the progression is when the user clicks the button, the ugh.wav file plays. Currently, the code is in a file along side another file named "audio", which is where "ugh.wav" is kept.